# Visual Basic - How to disable ease of access?

Tags: vb.net, windows, accessibility

I've made an application in Visual Basic. A few days ago, I got a message from a user telling me that the application had some errors. I found out that the Windows feature "Change the size of all items". I tried enabling it myself, and it made the application look horrible (Things that suddenly don't fit anymore etc..)

Is there any way to disable that feature just for my application? Preferably without the user having to do anything.

I tried to search online for a solution, but I didn't find anything. Maybe I'm searching using the wrong keywords?

Comment: This is called "font scaling". And no, you can't disable it just for your application, and you shouldn't want to do so. What about users who actually have vision issues, who need the larger fonts in order to use their computers? The solution is to properly fix your app, and test it using large fonts to make sure it looks and behaves properly. It's part of the job of writing software.

Comment: This isn't a quick fix, but it's worth mentioning that WPF handles this issue a lot better.

Comment: I agree that it's part of writing software, the problem is: it only happens at 125%. At 150%, the application whole application just gets bigger, instead of just the text and images. Is there a way to force that behaviour at 125%?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of TableLayoutPanel / FlowLayoutPanel, docking and anchoring, which gives you proportional sizing capability at a relatively low cost (programming effort). TableLayoutPanel has an option to set `AutoSize` for any cell, which in English means "make sure this control fits".

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is some kind of relative sizing for your fonts and elements. As a commenter said, WPF handles this very well. So one work around would be to redesign your UI in that. I understand that's not practical though. I'm guessing VB uses Winforms (?). If it does, then I'm not sure if that does dynamic font sizing or not.

An easier approach is a guideline, whether in your documentation or similar, stating that for best results this application should be used at 100% zoom or font size, etc. It might be worth giving that a shot.

You really don't want to be turning off people's accessibility settings. That will make you none-too-popular.